# Sendgrid and java

Tags: java, sendgrid

I am using the java api for sending sendgrid mail. Design the dynamic transactional template. I send from java the request with the required attributes. In sendgrid the empty personalization attribute arrives. I appreciate who can support me.

Java

```
Mail mail = new Mail();
if (!subject.isEmpty()) {
  mail.setSubject(subject);
}
Personalization personalization = new Personalization();
mail.setFrom(createFromEmail());
if(fields!=null) {
  for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : fields.entrySet()) {
    personalization.addSubstitution(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
  }

}
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : dynamicTemplateData.entrySet()) {
  personalization.addDynamicTemplateData(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
Email to = new Email();
to.setName(toName);
to.setEmail(toEmail);
personalization.addTo(to);
mail.addPersonalization(personalization);
mail.setTemplateId(templateId);
SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(GlobalVariable.getInstance().getSendGridApiKey());
Request request = new Request();
try {
request.setMethod(Method.POST);
request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
request.setBody(mail.build());
Response response = sg.api(request);
if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
   return true;
}
} catch (IOException ex) {
//TODO: WRITE ERROR LOG
return false;
} catch (Exception e) {
```

GlobalVariable.EscribirError(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7da3.png).getClassName(), Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7da3.png).getMethodName(), e, "");
    }

Template Sendgrid

```
</table>
{{#each personalizations}}
<table class="module" role="module" data-type="text" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;">
<tr>
<td style="padding:45px 45px 0px 45px;line-height:22px;text-align:inherit;"
height="100%"
valign="top"
bgcolor="">
<div style="text-align: left;"><span style="color:#333333;">Hola {{this.dynamic_template_data.subject}}
</span></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:30px 45px 30px 45px;line-height:22px;text-align:inherit;"
height="100%"
valign="top"
bgcolor="">
<div style="text-align: left;"><span style="color:#333333;">Para finalizar tu compra te hemos redireccionado a www.portsaid.com
Próximamente vas a poder completar este proceso a través de nuestra aplicación.
Tu selección:
</span></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Request 
    {
    "from": {
      "name": "Provashop",
      "email": "hola@provashop.com"
    },
    "personalizations": [
     {
      "to": [
     {
      "name": "Alejandro",
      "email": "prueba@gmail.com"
     }
    ],
    "dynamic_template_data": {
      "subject": "Extenal Store",
      "items": [
      {
     "idSearchingClothes": 0,
     "createdOn": null,
     "lastModified": null,
     "deletedOn": null,
     "clothes": {
     "idClothes": 0,
     "name": null,
     "description": null,
     "status": 0,
     "createdOn": null,
     "lastModified": null,
     "deletedOn": null,
     "gender": null,
     "clothesDesc": [

```
]
},
 "idUser": 0,
 "name": "CAMISA",
 "price": 390.0,
 "idStoreCatalog": 1,
 "idProviderItem": 82,
 "providerCode": "82",
 "brand": null,
 "url": "https://marketing-image-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/d13f90f1285040cd12f86d57ab9e61fee852def9f17e9d65c7a875b213c0fc414235679aa4016327adad5e78758cd9d131db32da4385e226d43fe01cfcd273eb.png",
"productId": 0,
"idVariation": 54,
"bought": false
 }
 ]
 }
 }
],
"template_id": "d-74bb8c95637147968e62e47b86362733"
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7da3.png)

Comment: Hi Alejandro, could you show us your code?

Comment: Hi Michael McMullin already place the code

Comment: One should at least _log_ the exceptions.

Comment: Joop Hi, If you are registering the exceptions. No exception in fact I send the email but it does not show the information